# If F is a non-empty finite subset on Real number,Show that F is Closed in $R$,but does not open in $R$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Please check my proof

suppose set of the complement of $F$ is $B$

For any inteval in $R$ it exist $x\in R$ and every inteval in $B$,it exist any x from $R$ and no number can't be exist in inteval in $B$.

Therefore it is open then F is closed

But I can't prove the second part that show it is not open

Anyone can give a hint ?

Comment: You can see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185258/every-finite-subset-of-the-real-numbers-is-closed?rq=1)

Comment: If $x\in F$ and $F$ is open, then $x\in I\subseteq F$ for some interval $I$. But $I$ is infinite, so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every nonempty finite subset $F$ of $\Bbb R$ is closed, as mentioned in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185258/every-finite-subset-of-the-real-numbers-is-closed?rq=1). Choose $x\in F$. Then any open interval $I$ that contains $x$, we have $I\not\subset F$ (this is because $I$ is an infinite set while $F$ is finite). This shows that $F$ is not open.